# Deploying Flask Application with pandas to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pandas, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I a new to AWS. Trying to deploy a simple flask application to AWS. I had no problem until I included pandas package.

No even with the simplest application I get errors such as "your requirements.txt file is invalid".

My test application is very simple: 
There are only two files in the folder
application.py and requirements.txt.

### Application.py is basic:

```
from flask import Flask
from pandas import DataFrame

application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route("/")
def home():
            return "hello pandas "


if __name__ == '__main__':
            application.run()
```

---

Requirements file was created with pip freeze

```
boto3==1.4.1
botocore==1.4.60
click==6.6
docutils==0.12
Flask==0.11.1
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.8
jmespath==0.9.0
MarkupSafe==0.23
numpy==1.11.2
pandas==0.19.0
python-dateutil==2.5.3
pytz==2016.7
s3transfer==0.1.7
six==1.10.0
```

### Werkzeug==0.11.11

I have seen posts recommending choosing a bigger instance type than t1.micro that is default. I have done that as follows:

```
 eb create -i m4.large --timeout 100
```

but still no luck.

If anyone has deployed flask application that uses pandas to AWS successfully please advise on the best way to do that. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem deploying a django app to EBS with pandas, and the issue was that there are certain C libraries that need to be installed first. Just add this in your .ebextensions folder:

```
commands:
  install_devtools:
    command: yum -y groupinstall 'Development tools'
```

Heads up, I believe that this will only work on sizes T2 small and above.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion. The deployment seems to have worked but my scripts errors out saying that it can't find pandas.

Comment: I would ssh into the server and check that pandas is installed correctly before running the file above. It still seems like a requirements.txt error to me, but at the moment it is impossible to tell. At the very least if you ssh in you can avoid constantly deploying to debug.

Comment: Thanks. I  have tried that as well. I ended up (for  now) installing my flask application and running it using python3 without apache or beanstalk for now.